# how to put search and cart icon into category part

Tags: magento2, category, search

How to get search to be in category part, please look at the picture below even cart icon[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will want to do this via default.xml. Ideally: `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme-name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

Here we will call on the minicart element and move it to your nav section or where you'd prefer, ex. `<move element="minicart" destination="top.links" />`

Then we will want to go into the respective template file in my case top_links.phtml and we will call on the childhtml so we can render our cart like so: `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart'); ?>`

The same will be done for the search.

Comment: This doesn't work for me

Comment: can you share what you have done?

Comment: I have solve my problem i added additional class using javascript then i moved it using css